# Filter foreign key data entered by a user in a Django form

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I have this Model that has a foreign Key. I want anytime a user if filling the form, Only the data entered by the user in the foreign key model should be shown to him as a dropdown.

```
Model.py


class Nomination(models.Model):
    fullname = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    nominee_id = models.CharField(max_length=100,  default=increment_invoice_number, null=True, blank=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='nominations_images')
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150, blank=True)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    createdby = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
```

```
forms.py
class CategoryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CategoryForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # access object through self.instance...
        self.fields['createdby'].queryset = Award.objects.filter(createdby=self.instance.user)

    class Meta:
        model = Category

        fields = "__all__"
```

This is the error I get.

```
'Nomination' object has no attribute 'user'
```

Comment: Is 'createdby' your Nominiation's user foreign key? If so (Assuming your variable is named nom_obj), try accessing nom_obj.createdby.user. Your error is telling you that you are accessing a field that doesn't exists in the model.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand how you got this error, because you have form for `Category` model and `self.instanse` should contain `Category` object, not `Nomination`. Anyway, if you have to use current user for form filtering, you can get it as form argument.

forms.py

```
class MyFilteredForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['createdby'].queryset=Award.objects.filter(createdby=user)
    ...
```

views.py

```
class SomeView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = MyFilteredForm(request.user)
        return render(request, 'form.html', {'form': form})
```

It can contains mistakes, but i think you get my idea.